# Compressing a large MP4 file that is on 2.30mins long

Tags: file-formats, conversion, mp4, compression

I have been sent a video that is only 2.30 mins long. But is a whopping 168mb, unfortunetely this has to be embedded into an app - so I need it as small as possible. I need to get the file size down big time.

It's attributes are Frame Width 1920 x 1080. 25fps data rate: 8690 kbps
Total bitrate 9008kbps

It will be going on a tablet that is 1040px at potrait.

What is the best way to shrink the file size?

Comment: if its going to be embedded into the App (as part of the download or distribution) you could compress it to say 720p using something like Handbrake at a lower bit rate to get it smaller in size

Comment: Will it be played full screen on the tablet? Or in a window? What resolution is that?

Comment: Ask to the person who sent you the video for reencoding it with lower bitrates. If for some reason you can not do that tell me what softwares do you work with. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to one nicely done piece of software which can enable you to compress this file, it is called [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/). Its encoder options provide for manipulating the Frame width, rate, quality and resulting format size.